# Optimizing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse IDE for Java EE 
Version: 4.3.2
Build id: M20140221-1700

My Compaq Laptop is a Core i3 M350 @ 2.27 Ghz with 8GB RAM running on windows 8.1 Pro 64bit.
And The JDK version is 1.7.0_40 64bit

I have disabled the validation check and the spell check but I have still noticed the IDE is lagging a lot and it freezes most of the time.

the eclipse.ini file is:

```
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
```

What would be the best eclipse.ini setting for me?

--UPDATE--
a copy of the workspace log file:

```
!SESSION 2014-04-21 18:23:18.129 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-04-21 18:23:31.716
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-04-21 18:23:31.743
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Amin'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 4 4 2014-04-21 18:23:42.500
!MESSAGE A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved taglib indexes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-04-21 18:44:46.343
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Compacting resource model".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:799)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.StringPool.add(StringPool.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.storeStrings(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode.storeStrings(DataTreeNode.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.storeStrings(DeltaDataTree.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.shareStrings(ElementTree.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.shareStrings(SaveManager.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.StringPoolJob$1.run(StringPoolJob.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.StringPoolJob.shareStrings(StringPoolJob.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.StringPoolJob.run(StringPoolJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-04-21 18:44:50.985
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-04-21 18:44:54.450
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Workbench Auto-Save Background Job".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EContentsEList.newNonResolvingListIterator(EContentsEList.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EContentsEList.basicIterator(EContentsEList.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil$ProperContentIterator.<init>(EcoreUtil.java:1294)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil$4.getChildren(EcoreUtil.java:1201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractTreeIterator.next(AbstractTreeIterator.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.attached(ResourceImpl.java:846)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl$ContentsEList.inverseAdd(ResourceImpl.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.NotifyingListImpl.addUnique(NotifyingListImpl.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.add(AbstractEList.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.createResourceWithApp(ResourceHandler.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$18.run(Workbench.java:1218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: Do you really need all of these arguments ?

Comment: This sounds more like you have a problem rather than just needing to optimize. Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for messages.

Comment: Instead of these parameters, just try vanilla eclipse w/ linux :-)

Comment: I actually don't know which parameters are extra...

Comment: remove all -vmargs except for  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m and than try

Comment: I did remove the extra arguments but still no changes... It keeps crashing . I have updated the question with the log file and I can see that there are couple of outofmemory error.. any idea what should I do?

Comment: I think I found the issue, But not sure yet.. (requires testing) The project that I was working on was very huge (over 54k files). the problem was the CVS branching issue so I was checking out the complete project and my IDE couldn't handle it. so now we have a proper branching and I have access to the required files. and so far the IDE is stable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was cause by the extra huge size of the Project (+54K files).

I had checkout the project from a wrong branch. so now I have the correct branch and I'm using it.

So far eclipse has worked OK without crashing.

Anyways thanks for your help.

My new eclipse.ini setting is:

```
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of pauses / freezes in Eclipse is often a sign that the JVM's garbage collector is struggling.  And the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exceptions explain why.  Your Eclipse is (was) on the brink of running out of heap, and the JVM was most likely running lots of "full" garbage collections in an attempt to keep Eclipse running.

You solved the problem one way ... by reducing the total size of the projects you had open.

Another solution is to increase the Eclipse JVM heap size, by changing the -Xmx option.  Assuming that your system has enough physical memory, it pays to be generous with the amount of heap space you give to Eclipse.  Conversely, no amount of fiddling with the other GC parameters will help much if the real problem is that your heap is too small ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had even tried to go up to 4GB (512,1024,2048,4096) for the heap size. but the IDE was still freezing. Right now I have set the Xmx to 2048 and I have reduced the project size. So far for last few days it's working very well.

Comment: Maybe you didn't have enough physical memory for a heap that big.  A really big heap on a machine w/o enough physical memory will result in VM thrashing.